# What happens to $l_1$ if i change coordinate system.

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $x =(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and also $x=\sum_{i=1}^m t_i u_i,$ where $t_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $u_i \in \mathbb{R}^n.$ Is it true that 
$||x||_1 \geq \sum_{i=1}^m |t_i|$ ?

Comment: $x=(1,0,0,-1)$. $x=1\cdot(1,-1,0,0)+1\cdot(0,1,-1,0)+1\cdot(0,0,1,-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

You should at least ask for $u_i$ to be unit vectors; otherwise they can be scaled at will, making the coefficients $t_i$ as large or as small as we want, for the same $x$.

If all $u_i$ are unit vectors, then $\|x\|_1 \le \sum_{i=1}^m |t_i|$ by the triangle inequality. But the reverse inequality;  they one you asked about, fails. A concrete example was given by David Mitra, so I'll just explain why you should expect counterexamples: if $u_1,u_2$ are   close to each other, then $x=u_1-u_2$ has small norm despite having coefficients $t_i=\pm 1$.

Essentially, you want $u_i$ to be a *$1$-symmetric basis* (look it up).